# Is there a way to get the x-th day of the next month in PHP?

Tags: php, time

I need to get the 4th day of the next month in PHP. Should be able to generate the date using `strtotime()`

I followed https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

tried strtotime('first day of next month +4 days') but it returns first day of next month always because of the precendence I think.

Comment: Try `<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days', strtotime('first day of next month'))); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code you can try. It is my hope that this will work for you

```
<?php
$d1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('first day of next month'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days', strtotime($d1)));
```

Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to do it using one string inside strtotime()

Comment: You add an unnecessary step here. You get a Unix time and convert it to string only to parse it back to Unix time immediately.